# Online resource to generate Java class from XML file

Tags: java, xml

Is there a website that will take a sample XML file as input and generate a (rough) Java class based on the elements (not data) in the file?  I have a fair-sized XML sample page that I have to do some work with and I'd rather not have to create the Java class representation for it.

If there's not a good online resource, an Eclipse plug-in or Windows-based executable will do as well.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample showing an XML file and how you would expect the Java code to look based on said XML?

Comment: The XML format shouldn't matter too much - I was hoping for a generic tool that would create a rough Java class that I could then go in and tweak.  John Volkya's suggestion of XMLBeans seems to be the far better way to go, as it provides a better way of doing what I have to do.

Comment: I was more wondering what it should look like based on sample input.

Comment: Even after 9 years this question is still actual, why StackOverflow closed it?

Answer (score 11):

I use the one from here:

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

It creates POJO for XML and JSON inputs

Comment: Can we download these classes as well. I was not able to download.

Comment: @ArghoChatterjee yes it is, but view html code, it is easy to copy from it :)

Answer (score 5):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

Your best bet is to generate an XML schema from the XML document, and then generate an object model from the XML schema using JAXB.

Example - Generating JAXB object model from XML Schema

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

You can leverage the Dali plugin in Eclipse to generate Java classes using JAXB:

- http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/

Comment: Perhaps a resource to generate the schema from the XML?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - John Volkya lead me to this to convert the XML to the schema. The XMLBeans toolkit may be exactly what I really need. http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd

Comment: @Haphazard - You could use the XMLBeans tool to generate an XML schema from the XML document, and then still use JAXB to generate the classes.  If you are using Java SE 6 the XJC tool is included.  If you are using Eclipse Helios you can right click your XML schema and choose:  Generate | JAXB Classes...

Answer (score 1):

A rather old question, but in case someone comes looking for an alternative to the ones already mentioned, here is one that generates a single file with inner classes

https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-java-converter

Comment: This is very strange. not all fields are represented