# Generate java class contains static fields mapped to resources files

Tags: java, android, xml, compilation, aapt

Let me say, I have `res.xml`file:

```
<res name="images">
   <path name="logo">assets/data/logo.png</path>
   <path name="img1">assets/data/img1.png</path>
   <path name="img2">assets/data/img2.png</path>
</res>
```

And I want to generate `Res.java` class automatically like this:

```
public final class Res {
    public static final String logo = "assets/data/logo.png";
    public static final String img1 = "assets/data/img1.png";
    public static final String img2 = "assets/data/img2.png";
}
```

to call any path by name like `logo` for example using static String field from that generated class `Res.java` from that `res.xml`:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo {
       String logo = Res.logo;
    }
}
```

So, I don't know how can I build `Res.java` automatically when I put my paths in `res.xml` (external resources files) simultaneously.

**Like** In Android environment there is `aapt` tool generates `R.java` class containing static fields as IDs which mention to external `res` file like drawables, values.

Now, How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm sure there are many different ways to do it. Though, It is not exactly clear what is your use case, so try to elaborate it a little bit. Also, I don't think you can dictate XML format or you have to use XSD instead of XML. Take a look at this for example: http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345501/online-resource-to-generate-java-class-from-xml-file for online converters, or this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-java-code-from-xml-schema.html to do it in idea.

Comment: @Sergei Sirik thanx for ur replying but, this is not what I want because this way create POJO class from Schema not really static values I put it on XML file. I want to create something like AAPT in Android where I can to separate code and design (xml) but only the link between code & design is R.class and that I need.